# How to let specific user to upload media files in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions

I wanted to let only some authenticated user(or use have specific permission) can upload media file with ImageField or FileField in Django.

I tried to find out a way to this.
I could find only way to let authenticated users view media files by apache basic or digest authentication with wsgi.

Temporarily, I changed media file to chmod 777 to allow anyone can upload images. But I don't think it is good way with security issues.

Is there any way to let only specific user(i.e users in specific group or users has specific permission) upload media file in Apache?

I can do permission check to let specific users can upload in views in Django. But media folder remains 777. I don't want to remain that anonymous users can have read write permission for media folder.

Comment: Please do ls -la in your Linux console in the parent directory and I will try to help.

Comment: What information should I give you? media folder is drwxrwxrwx 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096

Comment: Ok now do a top and tell me what user is running your uwsgi or gunicorn process.

Comment: I can't understand what you wanted exactly. there is media folder which is 777 permission under /home/ubuntu. a user in ubuntu is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using django-rest-framework.

You can define [Object level permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions) in django.

```
# permissions.py

class IsAllowedToUpload(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow certain users to upload media
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view, obj=None):
        # write permission that allows only certain type of users to upload media. 
        # Note that this method should return True of False only.
        return request.user.user_type == 'TYPE_YOU_WANT_TO_ALLOW'
```

Then in your views.py which is handling upload functionality.

```
class MyExampleView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAllowedToUpload, )
    # code #
```

Ok if you want to allow only logged in users there are some pre defined permission classes that you can use directly for ex. `IsAuthenticated`
check this : [Ready to use permission classes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated)

P.S You have to maintain `user_type` property for each user in your table and then you can manage each users like this.

Comment: your answer is managing permissions to let user have permission to upload something in django application, isn't it? Problem is that media folder will remains 777 chmod in Ubuntu server.

Comment: why do you want to change folder permissions ? You can manage permissions from application itself. This is wrong way of thinking I would say.

Comment: Because, I think, if you open your folder as 777 permission in ubuntu and if you let users upload and edit data(images, files and other stuffs) with this folder, It doesn't seem proper in terms of security issue.

Comment: You would have your django web application on some server. They access your website but cant access that machine files and folder.

Comment: I can see many article that leaving your permission 777 is bad idea security reason. Because anybody can read and write and execute it so it is more risky and someone can manipulate it. Well, What I wanted to do was like giving permission +w in apache to specific member in Django.